# Cardinality aggregation is retuning invalid totalcount when trying to execute for more number of data

Tags: elasticsearch

Cardinality Aggregation is returning incorrect result when index has more data. I have used below query to findout distinct value of txnids. In one day we will receive more than 60000 txns with duplicate entries. I went through few other threads, but i havent findout correct solution. I have tried with Precision_threshold also. Still not getting accurate distinct count values. Is it possible to get Distinct count? Because i have read in some documentation that ES will do only approximate distinct count. I have used below query:

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "dateRange": {
                            "from": "2022-03-14",
                            "to": "2022-03-14",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },                
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "status.keyword": [
                            "Success"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "id.keyword": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "search_after": [
        ""
    ],
    "aggregations": {
        "distinctRecords": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "recID.keyword",
                "precision_threshold": 40000
            }
        }
    }
}

My java code for cardinality
```

CardinalityAggregationBuilder distinctCount = AggregationBuilders.cardinality("distinctRecords")
.field("recID.Keyword").precisionThreshold(40000);

Comment: Yes you are right, cardinality aggregation returns approximate distinc count, have a look at this articale which solved the issue by using [Scripted Metric based solution](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7)

Comment: Yes. It has only ES Script. I am trying the same approach using java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scripted Metric Aggregation](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7)

Considering you are using RestHighLevelclient, instead of using cardinality Aggregation builder use ScriptedMetricAggregationBuilder.

> Script you can copy from either link provided or write your own script
> where "copy the script here" is present.

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("fieldName","recID.keyword");
        ScriptedMetricAggregationBuilder scriptedMetricAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.scriptedMetric("distinct_count")
                .params(params)
                .initScript(new Script("copy the script here"))
                .mapScript(new Script("copy the script here"))
                .combineScript(new Script("copy the script here"));
```

Comment: I have tried this code as below:

Comment: not working below:Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();params.put("fieldName","recID.keyword"); Sc..M..A..B..r builder = AggregationBuilders.scriptedMetric("distinct_count").params(params).initScript(new Script("state.list=[]")).mapScript(new Script("if(doc[params.fieldName] != null) state.list.add(doc[params.fieldName].value);")).combineScript(new Script("returnstate.list;")).reduceScript(new Script("Map uniqmap = new HashMap();int ct = 0; for(shardList in states){if(shardList != null){for(key in shardList) { if(!uniqmap.containsKey(key)){ct +=1;uniqmap.put(key, key);}}}}return ct;"));